# How to show year list in a descending order for DatePicker component in MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, material-ui, frontend

[image: MUI Datepicker]

I want to show the datepicker year list in Descending order but am unable to do. It shows min date at first and then goes down to the max date.

The code I wrote is written below.

```
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    <DatePicker
                        views={['year', 'month']}
                        label="Month"
                        value={selectedDate}
                        onChange={(value) => setSelectedDate(value)}
                        animateYearScrolling
                        minDate={'01-01-2000'}
                        maxDate={new Date()}
                    />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/momentutils-year-range-13emx?file=/App.js) on codesandbox to achieve the above mentioned descending order of years in datepicker. If you want more information on this, refer to this [feature request thread](https://github.com/mui/material-ui-pickers/issues/1112) on github.

```html
import React from "react";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "material-ui-pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
import { DatePicker } from "material-ui-pickers";
import moment from "moment";
moment.locale();

class LocalizedUtils extends MomentUtils {
  getYearRange(start, end) {
    const startDate = this.moment(end).startOf("year");
    const endDate = this.moment(start).endOf("year");
    const years = [];

    let current = startDate;
    while (current.isAfter(endDate)) {
      years.push(current);
      current = current.clone().subtract(1, "year");
    }

    return years;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { date: new Date() };

  handleDateChange = date => {
    this.setState({ date });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={LocalizedUtils}>
        <DatePicker
          clearable
          onChange={this.handleDateChange}
          showTabs={false}
          variant="outlined"
          minDate={new Date("01-01-1900")}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```